# How to solve x^x = const?

Tags: calculus

How to solve following equation:
$x^x = C$ as $x, C \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
I tried to use exponent and such that: $x\ln x = \ln C$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Applications

Comment: You'll find it easy enough to apply root-finding to $x \ln x = \ln C$ if you do not care to implement (or scout out an implementation of) Lambert's $W$ function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to solve $x^x = c$, for some number $c$. The answer $x$ cannot be expressed in terms of the common functions — polynomials, trigonometric functions, exponential, etc. — but you can express it in terms of another function that has been studied and given a name. Specifically, the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) is defined as the answer to a related question:

> If $x = W(z)$, then $xe^x = z$.

The relation is that
$$\begin{align}x^x &= c \\
x\ln x &= \ln c \qquad\qquad \text{ taking logarithms}\\
(\ln x)e^{(\ln x)} &= \ln c \qquad\qquad \text{ writing }x=e^{(\ln x)}\\
\ln x &= W(\ln c) \qquad \text{by definition of }W \\
x &= e^{W(\ln c)}
\end{align}$$

So the Lambert W function gives a name for what you want. To find the value numerically, you can use something like [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which is a very general method. For your problem, the method is something like the following (according to Wikipedia):

- Pick some value $w_0$ as your initial guess.
- If you know some value $w_j$ (where $j = 0, 1 \dots$ is an index), find the next value $w_{j+1}$ as
  $$w_{j+1}=w_j-\frac{w_j e^{w_j}-\ln c}{e^{w_j}+w_j e^{w_j}}.$$
- At each stage (for each $j$), $e^{w_j}$ is an approximation to the true value $x$ you want, and this approximation gets better as $j$ increases (as you perform more steps).

Answer (score 4):

It's not expressible in elementary terms. If you allow the $W$-function, you can write $y = \ln x$ to find $$y e^y = \ln C \implies y = W(\ln C) \implies x = e^{W(\ln C)}.$$