# How to solve $x^x=2$

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, exponentiation

I have no idea of how to solve $x^x=2$, and more generally, $x^x=n$, $n\in\mathbb{C}$.

I have tried many things, like taking log, exponentiating, etc. But none of these works. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve x^x = const?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1569750/how-to-solve-xx-const) – found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5Ex%20%3D%20n%24)

Comment: You need numerical methods (the Lambert-W function can also only be computed numerically)

Comment: @MartinR Yes, it helps! Thank you.